# C# extract a .zip file

Tags: c#, zip

In order to extract a .zip file I use:

```
using (var strm = File.OpenRead(file))
using (ZipArchive a = new ZipArchive(strm))
{
    a.Entries
        .Where(o => o.Name == string.Empty && !Directory.Exists(
            Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, o.FullName)))
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(o => Directory.CreateDirectory(
            Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, o.FullName)));

    a.Entries
        .Where(o => o.Name != string.Empty)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(e => e.ExtractToFile(
            Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, e.FullName), true));
}
```

In addition, this automatically creates folders if they are absent.

But there is a problem with files that have the extension **.sct**.
For example. if the .zip file contains only one file: `QuestLog.sct`, there is a problem.

[image: screenshot]

A file named `desktop.ini` is a priori contained in the .zip file to extract, but the problem is that this file is not there.

[image: screenshot]

This creates an error message because it tries to extract a file that does not exist. So I want to know if there is a possibility to get rid of this problem, for example by making a change in the C# code that can not try to extract the file `desktop.ini`.

This problem is not is not present with other **.sct** files.

I don't understand what happens.

Comment: Care to share that error message with us?

Comment: Also, could you please rewrite the code to use foreach-loops and format it so that we don't have to scroll left and right to get a grip on the code?

Comment: desktop.ini is hidden in Explorer by default by the "hide protected OS files" option, if you disable that it will likely appear in the Explorer view - although I would not think this would affect extraction.

Comment: @Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen
I have this problem only with this .sct file, not with other .sct files. 

The message: http://prntscr.com/lrljgw

Comment: Please post it as text, and not as a screenshot.

Comment: Also, where is the program located when you run it?

Comment: I found the problem. It's not related to the C# tool ...

In order to edit sct files I use a tool in order to decypt it. But, it seems to be a problem with a file, not with other. 

The only solution I found is to create a new folder with an unique name. After I need to copy paste the file in this new folder. After I need to copy the file and paste it in a folder in which I create in my patch folder. After I can create the .zip patch and it works. 

I don't understand why this tool create this problem, but I found how to work around the bug so that it does not happens.

Comment: By doing this, the desktop.ini file is not in the .zip file and therefore the error message does not appear.

I do not understand how it is possible because I have never placed the file desktop.ini in a .zip file but it seems to be automatically added in the .zip when I directly copy / paste the file that has the problem, without first placing it in a folder with a unique name.